# C# ASP.NET Core Razor pages: How to access route constraint within markup

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have a Razor page with the markup starting like so:

```
@page {id:int?}
...
```

Now, if you access the page on a path `/MyPage/5` the `id` parameter on the class method `OnGet(Int32? id)` will be set to the value `5`.

I'd like to display some conditional markup depending on the value of the id, is there a way I can access the id in the markup directly?

I tried `@id` but it says it isn't defined - which makes sense I guess.
I figured I could catch it in the `OnGet(..)` method and make it available through a property if there is no other way to do this directly. The downside to this approach is that I have to re-set the value every time a post-back happens.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Here is one way to access the `id` value.

```
<p>RouteData.Values["id"]</p>
```

#### Debugging

If you want to debug you can dump all the available `RouteData` on the page like this:

```
<p>@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RouteData)</p>
```

The output will look something like this:

```
{"DataTokens":{},"Routers":[],"Values":{"page":"/Index","id":"101273123"}}
```

Comment: Awsome, works perfectly. .. You're saying "one way" which implies there are potentially other ones, is there one which is shorter syntax wise?

Comment: I say "one way" because otherwise I sound more authoritative than I actually am. There *might* be a more concise way, but I haven't come across one yet. The ideal version would be something like `RouteData["id"]` instead.

Comment: hahah fair enough, and yes I agree, `RouteData["id"]` would be nice

Comment: Tiny update: We can use `RouteData` directly without the `@model` prefix.